# Getting an undefined method even though I have defined it in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, controller

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I want to have a tabbed menu on my admin login page, so I added the following to my app/controllers/admin_controller.rb file …

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :must_be_admin, only: :index

  def index
    @page_id = "index"
  end

  def menu_builder(page_id)
    tabs = ['Current Hacks','Add New Hack','Approve Hacks']
    content = ""
    tabs.each do |tab|
      content << if page_id == tab
        content_tag('li', content_tag('a', tab, :href => nil ), :class => 'current') + " "
      else
        content_tag('li', content_tag('a', tab, :href => "/#{tab}" )) + " "
      end
    end
    content
  end
```

Here is what I have in my app/views/admin/index.html.erb file …

```
<h1>Admin#index</h1>
<ul>
    <%= menu_builder(@page_id) %>
</ul>
```

However, when I visit my /admin/index page, I get this error

```
undefined method `menu_builder' for #<#<Class:0x007f861bfe9900>:0x007f861bff36f8>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: methods defined in controllers are actually actions, so you are unable to define a method in controller, which passes parameters. You need a helper for `menu_builder(page_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a rails method to be available inside your views,you must define it in `helpers` and **not in controllers.**

for example

```
admin_helper.rb

   def menu_builder(page_id)
     ###definition
   end
```

so now ,this method can be called within any views inside `admins/` coming from `admins_controller.rb`
but if you want it to be available to all views,then you must add it in `application_helper.rb`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use controller actions right into your views (they are called from routes via HTTP requests).

You need the `menu_builder` method to be defined in an AdminHelper module, and then call `helper AdminHelper` in your `AdminController`.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Hey it is looking this method in its helper . define that method in helper and then call it the view. You cannot call controller methods from a view..

Comment: You can use `:helper_method` to define it as usable by the view

Answer (score 0):

Please add `menu_builder` method to AdminHelper(*app/helpers/admin_helper.rb*). Otherwise, add `menu_builder` method to some other helper and include that helper in your AdminController. It is preferable to have `menu_builder` method in AdminHelper.

Methods in a controller generally meant for "actions", typically have to be defined and consumed through Routes.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the method from controller to any helper maybe applicaiton_helper then you are able to create view a you need